# Measurable function in $L^2$-norm

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a measurable function. Assume you know that

$$\sup_{||g||_2=1} \left|\int fg\,\right|$$ exists. Does this mean that $$\sup_{||g||_2=1} \left|\int fg\,\right| = ||f||_2?$$

Comment: What can you say about the map $g \mapsto \int fg$?

Comment: If you know that the measure space is semifinite, then yes.

Comment: @DanielFischer, it is a bounded linear function and therefore the RRT tells us that $f \in L^2$ and thus the equality must hold?

Comment: Well, we know that there is a $h \in L^2$ such that $\int fg = \int hg$ for all $g\in L^2$. Whether that implies $f\in L^2$ is a different matter, for which PhoemueX's comment is important.

Comment: @PhoemueX could you give me a hint how I could show it for a finite measure?

Comment: @DanielFischer of course, you are also invited to give me a hint.

Comment: Let $E = \{x : f(x) \neq h(x)\}$. From the fact that $\int (f-h)g = 0$ for all $g\in L^2$, what can you deduce about the possible values of $\mu(A)$ for measurable $A \subset E$?

Comment: Why is the map $g \to \int fg$ bounded?

Comment: @DanielFischer if $\mu(A)>0$ we take $g$ to be the function that is $1$ if $f>h$ and $-1$ if $f<h$, then we would get a non-zero result which is a contradiction, right?

Comment: @zhw because the sup exists?

Comment: @user167575 Well, almost. There is another point to watch out for. Look at PhoemueX's comment again. What other point may play a role?

Comment: @DanielFischer I assumed the measure to be finite, so we know that my $g \in L^2$

Comment: Okay, if the measure is finite, it is in particular semifinite, and the conclusion holds. In general, if the measure is not semifinte, you could have $f$ nonzero on a set of infinite measure such that every measurable subset is either a null set or has infinite measure. Every $L^2$ function must vanish (a.e.) on such a set, so $f$ need not be in $L^2$ then.